# Laravel 5.2 - Error 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Recently I fought with Laravel 5.2 a lot. I manage to install it on localhost which was running the same environment (apache, php, mysql) as real server where I try to put all the files. But even everything was the same I get the error 500 on the server.

I read the forums a lot and found the possibility of incorrect .htaccess. I check it several times and it was OK. I read the forums more and found the problem with storage permissions. Again I check it several times and OK.

Finally because I did not find the answer for my question I look for the mistake by myself. I go through the lines of the code and searching where is the code stacked. And found it! It was so weird! The mistake comes through the line, where simple variable was returned in the function. I never saw it.

At the end I manage space on another server (bit better hardware configuration) and everything runs fine. :)

Do you have any type of experience with that? Did you find specific rootcause (for ex. slow processor, not enough RAM or what?) ? At the end I must say I was not missing any specific PHP plugin. As I mention on the beginning - localhost and server has the same environment.

Comment: have you checked the error log?

Comment: 500 is not Laravel related your webserver configuration is wrong (permissions to folders are not set)

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: Your issue is that the local version is not working in the live server & getting 500 Error, isn't it  ?

Comment: I checked the error log and it is empty (laravel log, php error log and apache log - all without any message). My local version is not working in the live server that's true - of course I change my .env file to correct values of the live server.

Comment: I check the permissions to folders and should be 777 right? So it is. To be sure I change permissions to whole project and still the same. :(